# How to create Invoice Number in Text box and auto increment it on button click?

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-applications

I am using Asp.net(C#), and SQL Server. In web application I want 5 digit Invoice number in text box, and after clicking on button the gridviews data to be saved in database, and then invoice number in the text box should be increment by one...and so on. I used this code =>

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double ID = 00001;
    txtinvoiceno.Text = Convert.ToString(ID);
```

and

```
protected void btnsavef1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ID++;
    var no = Convert.ToInt32(ID);
    txtinvoiceno.Text = Convert.ToString(no);
}
```

but it shows in the output only single digit 1, and increment it only once time i.e.2, and further increment is not working.

Anyone have any idea on this??

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: Use the `INT` datatype instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
           { 
               int ID = 1; 
               txtinvoiceno.Text = ID.ToString("D5");
             }
        }

        protected void btnsavef1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int ID = Convert.ToInt16(txtinvoiceno.Text );
            ID++;
            txtinvoiceno.Text = ID.ToString("D5");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I doubt this will even compile, as within `btnsavef1_Click` the variable `ID` is not defined. You probably want `ID` to be an instance-variable:

```
class MyClass {
    private int ID = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtinvoiceno.Text = this.ID.ToString("D5");
    }

    protected void btnsavef1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ID++;
        txtinvoiceno.Text = this.ID.ToString("D5");
    }
}
```

Furthermore you won´t actually store the formatted number. Simply store the number as integer and do the formatting within your events-code using `ToString` and [format-specifiers.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#DFormatString)

Answer (score 1):

You´re looking for *formatting*, which is very easy in your case:

```
   //DONE: int, not double - do you want to deal with round-up errors?
   //DONE: ID should be a field, not a local variable
   private int ID = 0;

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // whenever you want 5 digits - just put 5 zeroes when formatting
       txtinvoiceno.Text = ID.ToString("00000");
       ...
   } 

   protected void btnsavef1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       ID += 1;
       // once again: want 5 digits - put 5 zeroes when formatting
       txtinvoiceno.Text = ID.ToString("00000");
   }
```

A better choice, IMHO, is to convert `ID` into *property* and hide formatting there:

```
   private int m_ID;

   public int ID {
     get {
       return m_ID;
     }
     set {
       m_ID = value;
       txtinvoiceno.Text = m_ID.ToString("00000"); 
     }
   }      
   ...
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     // Just assign
     ID = 0;
     ... 
   }

   protected void btnsavef1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     // Just increment 
     ID += 1;
   }
```

Comment: Good idea. Enables to always synchronize the `ID´ with its text-field automatically.

Comment: I used this code, but it still not increment after 000002. It just incremented first time only..

Comment: @chirag: I can't *reproduce* the error; need more code: are you trying to change/increment/decrement `ID` in other parts of the routine?

Comment: see, sir  while the http web page is stateless, when i click on button it increment first time and then when page is postback it get its initial value i.e. 1. therefore it cant move on to 3 then 4 and so on...thats the problem I am having...Do you have any solution for it??

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private double ID=0;
        public Form2()
        {
              InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
         double ID = 00001;
         txtinvoiceno.Text = Strings.Format(ID, "000000")
        }

   protected void btnsavef1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     ID++;
     var no = Convert.ToInt32(ID);
      txtinvoiceno.Text = Strings.Format(no, "000000")
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear, Beldi  sir, your answer is correct, but you give answer regarding window application. I am working on web application...

Comment: Yeah but it the same,you copied just the procedures !

Comment: see, sir while the http web page is stateless, when i click on button it increment first time and then when page is postback it get its initial value i.e. 1. therefore it cant move on to 3 then 4 and so on...thats the problem I am having...Do you have any solution for it??

Comment: Yes i have solution for you ,have a look at my seconde answer,if taht solved your issue please mark the answer

Answer (score 0):

you need to format only result number after increment.

```
protected void btnsavef1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ID++;
  var no = Convert.ToInt32(ID);
  txtinvoiceno.Text = no.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
}
```

if **ID=7**
your result will be after Increment
will be  **00008**